# How to add .corp TLD as redirect uri for google oauth

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, tld

Seems like it is not currently possible to add redirect uris having the TLD `corp` for a 
Client Id in Google's Developer Console.

While it is working to add a redirect uri like: `http://my.berlin`, uris like `http://my.corp` are going to fail.

Is there a workaround for that?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Since I landed on this question looking for a way to add custom TLD Google Auth, I leave a note.

It is not possible anymore (again) to provide callbacks using non-public top-level domain. So `corp` is ☠️. So is `dev` BTW.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this seems to work now. Can add URLs with custom TLDs to the Google project settings. Enable the 'Google+ API' in the project. Seems to be working fine.